# Resend unathorized requests after changing token in Angualr8

Tags: error-handling, rxjs, jwt, angular8, interceptor

I'm new to angular 8.
I have an interceptor :

```
export class HttpRequestInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    private apiAddress = 'http://localhost:1080';
    private refreshTokenIsInProgress = false;
    intercept(
        request: HttpRequest<any>,
        next: HttpHandler
    ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        let cloneReq;
        //...
        // some codes like adding access token to header
        //...

        cloneReq = request.clone();
        return next.handle(cloneReq)
            .pipe(
                catchError((error: any) => {
                    if(error.status==401)//means token expired
                      {
                         //Here i need help
                         //Get NEW Token And Replace With previous And Resend Current Request
                      }
                    return of(error);
                })
            )
            ;
    }
}
export const httpInterceptorProviders = [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: HttpRequestInterceptor, multi: true },
];
```

my requests are like:

```
return this.http.get(url).subscribe();
```

As I mentioned,if request returns 401(unauthorized) I need to get new token (JWT) from server , replace it with previous one, and then resend CURRENT request;
there is no problem on getting new token!
the problem is replacing new token and resend request;

i searched and googled form many hours but ...
i thought i can reach it by using **retry()** and **retryWhen()** , but they can't change request parameters.
thank you all buddy

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested the code, but you can try wrap the request into higher order function and get access to request object, also allow function to be called recursively until condition is met.

```
      const repeatRequest=(cloneReq)=>next.handle(cloneReq)
        .pipe(
            catchError((error: any) => {
                 if(error.status==401)//means token expired
                  req=........ // modify your request here
                  return repeatRequest(req)
                return of(error);
            })
        )
        cloneReq = request.clone();

        return repeatRequest(cloneReq)
```

Comment: thank you! it doesn't work. but i think i can edit it and get result. i will tell you bro.